# Remove "shutdown" but keep "hibernate" in Windows 10 Pro's start menu

Tags: shutdown, hibernate, wake-on-lan

I have a PC which I would like never to shutdown but always hibernate instead. I want to be able to use Wake-on-WAN and have problems due to the PC losing its entry in the router's ARP table when it's shut down for more than 15 minutes (even with fastboot disabled).

Mainly, I want to prevent myself from accidentally clicking on shutdown option in the start menu. This is not a case where security and malicious users are a concern.

Ideally, I would like to hide just the "shutdown" option from the start menu.

I spent a lot of time browsing for a solution but all of them remove the "hibernate" option together with the "shutdown" option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Even more ideally, If someone is an expert on wake-on-wan functionality, making sure that it works with the PC in shutdown mode would remove the need for the above-mentioned solution.

Comment: I know the feeling. I too had the same problem. For me the best option was combining group policy to remove the shutdown (and hibernation) from the start menu, and create a new shortcut that does `shutdown /h` and pin it to the start menu. Also, don't forget to change the powerbutton from shutdown to hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved my problem is as follows:

I disabled all power options and created two .cmd (or .bat) files, one to hibernate my PC, the other one to restart it. [Picture of my start menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvfWn.jpg).

Since using "shutdown.exe -h" made WoW unusable, i used `PsShutdown.exe` (a free tool which could be found online).
Here is the script for both files:

> PsHibernate.cmd

```
@echo off
psshutdown -h -t 0
```

> PsRestart.cmd

```
@echo off
psshutdown -r -t 0
```

I create two shortcuts to these files, shortcuts with admin privileges, and put them in my start menu folder, and pinned them.

**Note:** First run requires user input so be sure to try it out at least once.